# Using Address Locality field as Entity Reference

Tags: entities

Im using Drupal 8.

In content-type-A, I have a field type Address with country and locality as required fields. I want locality as an entity reference to be use in content-type-B.

Whenever I create an entity reference view, its giving me the list of content title as a result. I added locality as field(and/or remove content title) and select it as search fields. I am getting no results on it.

I assume locality results would showed up.

Comment: im using group module on this. UPDATE: whenever I add relationship(group and group content) to the entity reference view, its giving me zero results. I added a relationship for me to get the field locality in an Address field of a content type.